# South African working for US company in SA; need to go work at client in Canada

Tags: visas, canada, work

I am currently employed by a US owned company in South Africa.

The US branch has obtained a contract with a Canadian client for a couple of months (up to 6 months).

The US branch requires of me to go work at the client site for the contract period performing software configurations and support.

I have searched online for the past couple of days trying to find the exact answer but have failed to find something 100% concrete.

Will I require a work visa to work at the client site in Canada?

I will not be paid by the client directly; the client pays our US branch directly which will then pay my normal salary into my South African Bank account.

If I go for 6 months, can I take my wife and kids with me on the same visa?

Comment: If your company is large enough for this kind of cross border work, surely they should have the means to pay an immigration attorney to figure out this for you?

Comment: Do you need a work permit to work in Canada?
 http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/apply-who-nopermit.asp

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie on the other hand, the employee has a lot more to lose than the company or an immigration lawyer.  If the employee receives incorrect advice from the company or its attorney, the employee may wind up with an adverse immigration history.  That will affect the employee for a long time, potentially the rest of his or her life, while having little impact on the company or its attorney.

Comment: @phoog Agreed however I expect employees in those situations to do some checks on what the lawyers suggest, NOT the one to do the heavy lifting from scratch as it appears OP is having to do.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie That is certainly true.  I had intended to mention something like that in my comment but forgot to include it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a work permit to do the kind of work you mention in Canada. Use this tool to figure it out:

[Do you need a work permit to work in Canada?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/apply-who-nopermit.asp)

> Also on that question, If I go for 6 months, Can I take my wife and
>   kids with me on the same visa ?

Yes you can, **if** they are granted visas.